# Side Menu of IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on a ios application and there is an issue on it's side menu.
Does the Side Menu of ios application can be drag completely on screen? if not then kindly give me the solution.

Comment: what side menu you are using?. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i just want to ask that is this possible to drag the side menu 50% of the screen or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SWRevealViewController library, and set `rearViewRevealWidth` properties to your width. If you want rearViewRevealWidth = 50% of device's screen, just get screen's width / 2. It's very simple! For tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Answer (score 7):

There is [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library for your purpose. Just set `visibleContentWidth` to 0 for `TransitionOptionsBuilder`.
Here is an example:

```
override func menuTransitionOptionsBuilder() -> TransitionOptionsBuilder? {
    return TransitionOptionsBuilder() { builder in
        builder.visibleContentWidth = 0
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu/blob/master/Sample/Sample/HostViewController.swift).